# Confused by the % sign and other things in disassembly

Tags: assembly, call, cpu-registers, disassembly

I disassembled this code

```
int main{

vector<string> temp;


}
```

The result is this

```
LEA ECX, %16I64X DWORD PTR[EBP + temp] 
CALL std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::
```

My questions are:

1. What does %16I64X doing here.
2. what does the line "std::vector, std::" means. I know that the instruction CALL called this but the one that has been called doesnt make sense. Is this an I/O redirection?
3. Im just confused of the logic of the disassembly becuase it loads the effective address and then called it. I am expecting something like moving first something in a specific address then loads its effective address then call it.

*Im just a beginner here. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Possibly `%16I64X` looks like it tells the assembler to use the short from (with 8 bit displacement) of the `lea` instruction.

Answer (score 0):

The "std::vector..." etc. is the full name of the constructor of `vector<string>`. "std" because it is declared in the std-namespace, "basic_string" because "string" is a typedef of `basic_string<char>` etc. When using templates the final generated names are often very long and hard to read.

The way I read this code is LEA ECX loads ecx with the address of "temp" variable, this is then passed to the constructor so that the object is created at the correct address.